# Pointing dynamically created gridview events to defined procedures

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I'm creating a Gridview dynamically based in an object data model, no problem with that, but I don't know how to point its events to defined procedures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using C#, declare the GridView and define its event handler. In this case for the RowDataBound event.

```
        GridView gv = new GridView();

        gv.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(gv_RowDataBound);
```

Then create the handler:

```
        protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            // your code
        }
        ...
```